# sql - Data with more than one record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following temporary table

[image]

Aim is to flag the data with more than one records and put `More than one records`

In my example below, if `Siren` appears more than once, I would have

```
Siren           ETS_RS                                 Voie                      Ville              nom_etp
348177155       POITOU-CHARENTES ENGRAIS  P.C.E. (SNC) BOULEVARD WLADIMIR MORCH  17000 LA ROCHELLE  More than one records
```

For records that are appearing once, I will have the single name of the company (here `nom_etp`)

```
Siren           ETS_RS                                 Voie                      Ville              nom_etp
344843347       PRESTIGE AUTO ROCHELAIS (SAS)          4  RUE JEAN DEMEOCQ       17000 LA ROCHELLE  NIGER
```

I tried a few things based on the idea  that if I can have a count of more than one, I could flag them easily and use them with a `CASE` :

First: I tried to do a count

```
WITH cte_ssrep_moraux AS (...)
SELECT SIREN,ETS_RS,Voie,Ville
,Denomination AS nom_etp,COUNT(SIREN)
FROM cte_ssrep_moraux
GROUP BY ETS_RS,Voie,Ville,Denomination,SIREN
```

It hits a snitch as all counts were equal to one and I have the same dataset as in the picture...

Second:

```
WITH cte_ssrep_moraux AS (...)
SELECT ETS_RS,Voie,Ville
,Denomination AS nom_etp,SIREN,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ETS_RS ORDER BY ETS_RS ASC) AS  xx
FROM cte_ssrep_moraux
GROUP BY ETS_RS,Voie,Ville,Denomination,SIREN
```

It hits a snitch as all counts were equal to one and I have the same dataset as in the picture...

I'm bit confused on what I should do next. I have the feeling will be an easy one and I'll face palmed myself.

Many thanks for reading my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CTE for this purpose

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT ETS_RS,Voie,Ville,Denomination AS nom_etp,SIREN,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ETS_RS ORDER BY ETS_RS ASC) AS  RN
FROM cte_ssrep_moraux
--GROUP BY ETS_RS,Voie,Ville,Denomination,SIREN
)
SELECT ETS_RS,
   Voie,Ville,
   CASE WHEN RN > 1 THEN 'More than one records'
        ELSE nom_etp
        END AS 'nom_etp',
        SIREN
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Yes @AndyK  you are :)

Comment: you helped me a great deal. Many thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

If this is your criteria:

> if Siren appears more than once,

Then the `group by` clause should only contain `Siren`:

```
SELECT SIREN, COUNT(*)
FROM cte_ssrep_moraux
GROUP BY SIREN
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

I'm not sure what you want to do after that, but this will return the `SIREN` values that appear more than once.

Comment: Hi @gordon-linoff, usually I would say yes but I'm within a CTE and it seems CTE does work well with a group by ... I tried the solution you proposed , to no avail ...

Comment: Have you aliased the column name?  You'll have to give it a name within the cte.

Comment: Hey @Nick I've aliases the columns

Answer (score 2):

If there is more than one row and you change every nom_etp to 'more than one record', you end up with identical rows. That's why I prepared some tweaked query. See following (table simplified for clarity):

```
CREATE TABLE Duplicates
(
    Id int,
    Name varchar(20),
    Item varchar(20)
)
INSERT Duplicates VALUES
(1,'Name1', 'Item1'),
(2,'Name2', 'Item2'),
(2,'Name2', 'Item3'),
(3,'Name3', 'Item4'),
(3,'Name3', 'Item5'),
(3,'Name3', 'Item6'),
(4,'Name4', 'Item7');
```

If you need just a query:

```
WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name, Item,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) RowNum,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY ID) TotalInGroup
    FROM Duplicates
)
SELECT Id, Name,
    CASE WHEN RowNum=1 AND TotalInGroup>1 THEN 'More records' ELSE Item END Item
FROM Numbered
```

If you need to normalize:

```
WITH Numbered AS
(
    SELECT Id, Name, Item,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) Number,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Id) RowNum,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY ID) TotalInGroup
    FROM Duplicates
)
MERGE Numbered AS tgt
USING Numbered AS src
ON src.Number=tgt.Number
WHEN MATCHED AND tgt.RowNum=1 AND tgt.TotalInGroup>1 THEN
    UPDATE SET tgt.Item='More'
WHEN MATCHED AND tgt.RowNum>1 THEN
    DELETE;
```

Table will look like below:

```
Id  Name    Item
--  ----    ----
1   Name1   Item1
2   Name2   More
3   Name3   More
4   Name4   Item7
```

If there are multiple rows with same id, first of them is updated  with 'More' constant, all other in the group are deleted.

Comment: Hi @pawel-dyl, very interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte
as
(
select siren,count(*) as cnt
from
yourtable
having count(*)>1
)
update t
set nom_etp='more than one records'
yourtable t where exists(Select 1 from cte c where c.sirenid=t.sirenid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you still want all the records, including the unique.

Then you can use COUNT as a window function.
With a CASE to choose what to display as nom_etp.

```sql
select Siren, ETS_RS, Voie, Ville,
(case when count(*) over (partition by Siren) > 1 then 'More than one records' else nom_etp end) as nom_etp
from cte_ssrep_moraux;
```

Comment: Hi @lukstorms getting there. One thing though: How would I pick the first record and remove the duplicate records ...?

Comment: You can do that via row_number. But you need a field that's unique in that table. Like the primary key. And something to order those duplicates. For example assuming Id is unique (untested) : 
`delete from cte_ssrep_moraux
where id in 
( 
  select id 
  from (
    select id, 
 row_number() over (partition by Siren order by ModifyDate desc) as rn 
 from cte_ssrep_moraux
  ) q
  where rn > 1
);`

Comment: Hi @lukstorms thanks for your answer; I found out the solution. I've put my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Please find what I did

```
WITH cte_ssrep_moraux AS (
SELECT SIREN,ETS_RS,Voie,Ville
,Denomination AS nom_etp,ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (PARTITION BY ETS_RS ORDER BY ETS_RS ASC) AS  Counting
FROM 
(my_initial_cte) AS tb
)
SELECT Siren, ETS_RS, Voie, Ville,nom_etp
FROM cte_ssrep_moraux
WHERE counting = 1
AND Siren NOT IN  (SELECT Siren FROM cte_ssrep_moraux WHERE counting > 1)
UNION ALL 
SELECT DISTINCT Siren, ETS_RS, Voie, Ville,'More than one records'
FROM cte_ssrep_moraux
WHERE counting > 1
```

Explanation: After the initial CTE, I tried many of the solutions mentioned above especially using the `CASE`.

Issue with the `CASE` was that it would put something like that

```
 Siren ETS_RS Voie  Ville     nom_etp
 xxxx  xyxy   xyzet Bordeaux  More than one records
 xxxx  xyxy   xyzet Bordeaux  More than one records
 xxxx  xyxy   xyzet Bordeaux  More than one records
 xxxy  zzzy   ssare Paris     Firm ABC
```

So instead of putting everything under a `CASE`, I said let's split that into 2 part :

1. First part would put everything with a counting equal to 1
2. Second part would put the rest with a counting that goes above 1 with a `DISTINCT`
3. Join the two results with an `UNION ALL` as the two sets have the same numbers of fetch rows